# Why does C# designer-generated code (like Form1.designer.cs) play havoc with Subversion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, version-control, windows-forms-designer

My workshop has recently switched to Subversion from SourceSafe, freeing us from automatic locks. This led to concurrent editing of the Forms, which is wonderful. But when multiple developers commit their changes, the code files created by the designer (all the files named `TheFormName.designer.cs`) cause conflicts which are very difficult to resolve.

As far as I can tell, this is because the code generated by the designer is heavily re-arranged whenever the user modifies it, no matter how little the actual change really did.

- How do I make these conflicts easier to resolve?
- Is there some way to tell the designer to modify the code less?
- How do you, the experienced C# teams, deal with concurrent modification of a Form?

Comment: Never had the problem with designer files (although I don't really do WinForms apps), but it generally does the same with csproj files which is very annoying :-(

Comment: OK, I put a bountey - I really wish I could find a good solution for this. I hope someone can help.

Comment: @StevenRobbins I think the situation for project files has improved with VS 2013 and newer. It does a pretty good job of not reordering MSBuild directives.

Comment: I guess I am too late for the bounty. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with C# or the Windows Form Designer, but looking at some `designer.cs` files I could find online they don't have a particularly complicated structure.

What parts of it are being re-arranged? I guess it's mostly the order of the properties in the `InitializeComponent()` method that's jumbled up?

If that's the case, you might be able to write a simple script that re-orders those lines alphabetically, say (especially if you never edit these files manually anyway), and use that as a [pre-commit hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) in Subversion.

Um, right... scratch that. The big red box at the bottom of that section says you're not supposed to modify transactions in hook scripts. But you might be able to find another way to run that script somewhere between the `designer.cs` file being changed and it being committed.

#### Edit:

Actually, given scraimer's comment on this:

> Total hack, but in the worst case, just before a merge, I could sort BOTH files, and make the merge simply a line-by-line affair...

Can't you let Subversion set an external merge program? I've been using [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), which can [run a preprocessor command before doing diffs or merges](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/preprocessors.html), so you could automate that process.

Comment: That sounds like a really really cool solution. Total hack, but in the worst case, just before a merge, I could sort BOTH files, and make the merge simply a line-by-line affair... Of course, this is somewhat like curing a patient by putting them in a blender and then putting them back together.

Comment: At least make sure you select a 3-way merge tool (like KDiff3). A 2 way merge tool can't really help you in resolving this kind of issues.

Comment: I implemented sorting, but it is tricky and I needed to fix it many times. Remember the items in designer have tree structure and their order respects it. Also, the code in .designer file is really built and executed, so for example when you are not lucky/experienced enough in sorting 3 parts of VerticalSplitter/HorizontalSplitter control, your application compiles, but you can get runtime exception from splitter, complaining about illegal set up of position of the splitter line.

Comment: I _am_ familiar with C# and WinForms designer. Sometimes I wish I was not, because it indeed has been a pain to work with it sometimes... You observations are correct, that it does not have a complicated structure. However, you can easily order the code without scripts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74873925/2505186

Answer (score 10):

Here are some things to try:

- Make things more modular. Use components like User Controls etc. to split forms into multiple, smaller physical files.
- Use presentation layer design patterns like MVP to move code out of views and into standard POCO classes.
- Recent versions of SVN allow you to take hard locks - use this to avoid complex merge scenarios.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, we've actually been already been making it all modular, just to allow us to work with with VSS, and we use no business code in our presentation layer (which are the `designer.cs` files). I was hoping for a more elegant solution than SVN locks, though. Thanks!

Comment: Well one "elegant" way would be to code them all by hand! ;-)

Comment: You rules are valid. However, there is also a solution to the actual problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74873925/2505186

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there is no silver bullet for this problem as the designer stomps all over the designer.cs.

All I can suggest is to minimise the use of the designer. Personally I only hook to events in code and only use the designer only for initialisation and positioning. As such it isn't too hard to fathom differences in a changeset ("oh, someone has added a button", "oh, someone has changed how it looks slightly").

Comment: I guess I really am asking for something as magical as a silver bullet! We're already minimizing the amount of code that goes into the designer.cs, not to mention even the code that got into any part of the GUI. I guess I am hoping for someone to come along with a creative solution...

Comment: I think there /is/ a silver bullet, at least theoretically: Visual Studio should just make **consistent** changes to this file, rather than arbitrarily move stuff around every time.

Comment: I know, I'm probably late on this one, but if the problem annoys you as much as me you can add your vote for improving matters on [visualstudio.uservoice.com](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2294243-don-t-scramble-designer-cs-files-on-updating-so-d).

Comment: I’ve submitted a [new uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/19808824-deterministic-ordering-of-initializecomponent-in-w) as the original was closed.

Comment: I don't know whether you could call my solution a silver bullet, but I think it comes close: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74873925/2505186

Answer (score 3):

Yep, Designer's random rearranging sure is irritating.  Does Microsoft use their own tools?  Does Microsoft look at what they check into version-control?  It boggles the mind.

Our team's "solution" is to hand-edit the Designer files after we're done editing them, to put things back to where they were, so that the text-based diff is readable, and so concurrent changes can be merged sanely.  Luckily, most of Visual Studio's rearranging is simple-minded, so this works.

Sadly, we've found that this step is necessary to verify correctness -- we've found cases where Designer silently removes things that are needed, leading to broken code.  So this step has to be done in order to work around whatever data-destroying bugs lurk inside.  Sigh.

Since Microsoft has a poor track record of fixing its bugs, the only solution may be to improve [Mono's WinForms Designer](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms_Designer) so that it's ready for prime time.

Comment: MS uses TFS which is poor at merging and mostly works on the old VSS-style 1-user-checkout at a time approach. So I guess MS people don't see the problem.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - neither source safe or TFS require locking of files, and they both merge concurrent changes just fine (sourcesafe has weird quirks with branch/merge, but that's a different story).

Answer (score 2):

It's true that the designer sometimes messes up the order of the controls in the code, which causes the file to look very different compared to a previous version. This indeed is a problem if the file is under version control.

However, I found that the designer works quite reliably even in very large forms and user-controls if you follow some rules, and in those rare case where it does not, I have a easy way to force the designer into arranging the controls in the "correct" order again.

My rules:

1. The comment at the top of `InitializeComponent()` in every `.designer.cs` says: *do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor*. Well, if you know what you're doing, then it's absolutely no problem to edit this file manually, because this is what you need to do. Just make sure you have a backup.
2. Typically, when you create a form or UC, you add some controls here and there and move them around until you find a nice arrangement. But in the `.designer.cs` file, the controls are ordered by the order of their creation, and not by your logic how they belong together.
   After finishing the creation of the form or UC, I reorder both the declarations (at the bottom of the file) and instantiations of the controls and their adding to the respective parent control (both in `InitializeComponent()`) until they are in the order that I want them to have. This makes it much easier to find them if you have to change a property of a control in the code.
   And it also makes it easier for version control, because you may easily see what part of your form or UC was changed just by seeing the place (rather towards top or bottom of the file?) of the change in a file comparison view.
   But changing the order in these 2 sections does not automatically change the order of all the parametrization code that comes after the instantiation part in `InitializeComponent()`. This will be done when you execute the solution to the OP's problem, which is described next.

If you work with rule #2, then you need to do the same finishing work that you need to do when you encounter the problem that the OP describes:
**You have to force the designer to arrange controls in the order that they have in the declaration and instantiation.**
This can be done in a quite simple way (which worked for me in 99% of the cases so far):

1. Save all files of the form or UC
2. open the designer view
3. move one of the controls (e.g. by selecting it and hitting 1x left arrow key)
4. optional: look at the `.designer.cs` file and/or save the form or UC
5. move the control back to have your intended design (e.g. by hitting 1x right arrow key)
6. save the form or UC

The designer will rewrite the whole `.designer.cs` file and your controls should now be in the "correct" order.

There are rare cases where this does *not* help. These include `DataGridViewRow`s in embedded `DataGridView`s and embedded `UserControl`s. In these cases I additionally do similar finishing work which includes adding and removing a button:

1. Save all files of the form or UC
2. open the designer view
3. add a button anywhere in the form or UC
4. optional: look at the `.designer.cs` file and/or save the form or UC
5. remove this button again
6. save the form or UC

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to truely avoid this problem when using a merge style source control system such as subversion is to hand code the forms and not use the designer.  Obviously, this would not be good because hand coding these forms can take a while.

The reason this happens is because the control properties are serialized by the designer in the order they are dropped on the form.  Cutting and pasting can effect this order as well as moving a control so that it has a new parent (such as moving a control on to a panel when it was previously directly on the form).

I had this problem on a large project and had to imploy a rather ugly approach - diff the designer.cs files against the check-in target revision and manually merge them using a merge tool.  This isn't ideal, but it is the only way I see this working consistently with svn or another merge style source control tool.

The other option would be to use a lock approach with source control, as others have pointed out, but this comes with unpleasant side effects as well.

Comment: Those are the solutions we've already been forced to employ, and they are not very satisfying. But thank you for your advice.