# How to diff changed form file - ( .Designer InitializeComponent )

Tags: c#, winforms, svn, merge, branch

Using Suversion and WinDiff its no problem to branch / merge class-projects and web-projects.

The only kind of project I can never merge are winform projects. The InitializeComponent method is always scrambled after only little changes.

Is there any good way to enable diff / merge for .Designer - files?

**EDIT:**

I used a 3 way diff like Bert suggested. It made things a lot more easy. But still Winform - files (.designer and .resx ) were not mergeable.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486670/why-does-c-designer-generated-code-like-form1-designer-cs-play-havoc-with-subv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a different method of ensuring that diffs are a bit more managable.  We have a trigger on checkin that will modify the designer files InitializeComponent section into a consistent and ordered manner, so that diffs show the real changes.

we want to split InitializeComponent into 4 sections - creation, layout suspension, setup and layout resuming.  Each of these sections are then separately ordered according to the names of the controls.

Comment: and @configurator: Same problem here. Do you happen to have trigger code to share?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Resharper, reformat (including sorting members and whatever) those files before checking in.

Answer (score -1):

Windiff was designed for comparing files. It uses a 2 way diff merge algorithm, that only allows you to see changes between two versions of a file, so you just have to guess which changes should be applied to a result file.

For merging you should really look into using a 3 way diff algorithm/tool.

In a 3 way diff the diff tool uses the original version of a file to extract the changes of your file (%mine) against the origin (%base) and their file (%theirs) against the origin and then applies all changes to the original version to create a single result. (And if there are any conflicts i

A very user friendly 3 way GUI diff tool that you can use for free is [SourceGear DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) (Recommended), but TortoiseMerge also implements a 3 way merge.

You can find a list of other common merge tools on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools).

Comment: This is a good suggestion in general, but is not relevant to the designer file merging problem.