# Sorting designer code on save

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

When opening a Form in the Visual Studio Designer, the generated designer files' contents get mixed up randomly. This includes the files

- Form.Designer.cs and
- Form.resx

When using a version control system this is a real nightmare.
Is there a way (extension?) that sorts and cleans up all designer files before saving? This would solve most of my VCS related issues with WinForms, as it reverses all the shuffling the designer does.

Comment: what do you mean mixed up? these are code generated files - modifying them could break your forms.

Comment: How would re-arranging the order of declarations break the code?

Comment: You might break the designers

Comment: No, it does not break anything. The designer does not care for any order in its generated code (which wouldn't make sense anyway).

Answer (score 4):

This problem sure does make merging difficult - I understand your pain.

Read this previous SO post:
"[Why does C# designer-generated code (like Form1.designer.cs) play havoc with Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486670/why-does-c-sharp-designer-generated-code-like-form1-designer-cs-play-havoc-wit)"

Basically you could create a tool to sort all the code alphabetically to give order to the random placement of code, but it is a hack and could involve a lot of pain itself. Personally I recommend changing your work practices to reduce this occurring.

- Reduce time between merges
- Limit access to a form to 1 developer at a time.
- Merge under the guidance of the developer who made the change, as they will know better what looks ok.
- Don't open the designer, if you are only making a "code change", ie nothing changes visually.
- Undo changes to the designer file before merges, if you are 100% sure that you didn't change anything.

Comment: All good advice IMO. Especially for the "limit access to a form to 1 dev at a time". I learned the hard way from VSS (and even TFS) that allowing multiple checkouts to something with a UI component is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @DeanOC, I totally agree, Merges can be troublesome enough. Once upon a time I used to use regions extensively, but I gave them up quickly because they really messed up the merges sometimes.

Comment: You are right, obeying these rules makes things better. But it's still pretty annoying. And from time to time things go wrong, because someone forgot to stick to the rules ;-) So I was hoping for an automated, bullet-proof solution.

Comment: Anyone knows if some out-of-the-box solution is available nowadays, in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tip about automatically sorting Form.Designer.cs; however, it does help with avoiding merge help with all modifications made to Form.Designer.cs-files by Visual Studio.

Instead of (or in addition to) [changing your work practices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24665877/814206) (by [Jonathon Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891496/jonathon-lee)) and especially the constricting "Limit access to a form to 1 developer at a time" do:

Ensure the Form.Designer.cs-file is organized according to Visual Studio in a separate commit before you make the real changes.

- Trigger a reorganization of the Form.Designer.cs-file by Visual Studio
  *(For me, moving a control from one cell in a `TableLayoutPanel` to an other and back again did the trick.)*
- Commit Visual Studio's changes and mark them as nothing changed.
- Make your modifications to the Form
- Trigger a reorganization of the Form.Designer.cs-file by Visual Studio
- Commit your changes and describing your work.

Results:

- This helps reviewers to distinguish changes to review from noise.
- This eases merging:

  - either, your version control system detects that two commits have the same effect and one is enough and it can merge without conflicts;
  - or, you manually resolve the conflict by applying just one of the cleanup commits and discard the other.

Comment: This is all good and well, but seriously, after almost 20 years of the same havoc someone should and could have kicked MS into their corporate balls to fix that. Its really annoying and totally unnecessary.